# JQuery, JSON and $.each - string not concatenating

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, I have a function which when called adds a table within a new row of an existing table, complete with results returned in JSON format by a restful API.

Code:

```
$(".transactionViewButton").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.on("click", function(){
        if($(this).closest("tr").next("tr").attr('id') != "itemsRow"){
            var rowAdd = "<tr id='itemsRow'><td colspan='8'><table class='table table-striped table-hover bureau-customer-table'><thead><tr><th>Item ID</th><th>Item Name</th><th>Cost</th><th>FSM Amount</th><th>End Cost</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

            $.getJSON("transactionItem.json", function(data){
                $.each(data, function (key, val){
                    rowAdd += "<tr><td>" + val.ID + "</td><td>" + val.Name + "</td><td>" + val.Cost + "</td><td>" + val.FSM+ "</td><td>" + val.EndCost + "</td></tr>";
                });
            });
            rowAdd += "</tbody></table></td></tr>";
            $(this).closest("tr").after(rowAdd);
        } else {
            $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

And the JSON test data:

```
[{
    "ID": "123",
    "Name": "Food Item 1",
    "Cost": "0.50",
    "FSM": "0.00",
    "EndCost": "0.50"
  },{
    "ID": "124",
    "Name": "Food Item 2",
    "Cost": "0.50",
    "FSM": "0.00",
    "EndCost": "0.50"
  },{
    "ID": "125",
    "Name": "Food Item 3",
    "Cost": "0.50",
    "FSM": "0.00",
    "EndCost": "0.50"
}]
```

The function works as much as it adds the new table, with heading row and with the closing row. It also will remove the new row if triggered a second time.

The problem is in the `$.each` part. I know its receiving the JSON data as inserting an alert before the `rowAdd +=` results in a response for each record. It just isn't adding the actual table row in to the `rowAdd` string for each record. Its like its just plain skipping that line. Also, there are no JavaScript errors either. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.get` is asynchronous. This means that all code dependant on the result of the request needs to be placed in the callback. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("transactionItem.json", function(data){
    var rowAdd = "<tr id='itemsRow'><td colspan='8'><table class='table table-striped table-hover bureau-customer-table'><thead><tr><th>Item ID</th><th>Item Name</th><th>Cost</th><th>FSM Amount</th><th>End Cost</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

    $.each(data, function (key, val){
        rowAdd += "<tr><td>" + val.ID + "</td><td>" + val.Name + "</td><td>" + val.Cost + "</td><td>" + val.FSM+ "</td><td>" + val.EndCost + "</td></tr>";
    });

    rowAdd += "</tbody></table></td></tr>";
    $(this).closest("tr").after(rowAdd);
});
```

Comment: A tiny change to your above did it `$(this).closest("tr").after(rowAdd);` became `$this.closest("tr").after(rowAdd);` and it works. Much appreciated.